# Efficiently converting an [Integer] to [Float] with Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, type-conversion

Here's a simplified example of the entries I have in the text files I'm reading --

```
Set1 1 2 3
Set2 6 7 8
```

I'm trying to write a function that can convert the above strings into a list of tuples --

```
[("Set1", [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), ("Set2", [6.0, 7.0, 8.0])]
```

This is the function I've written --

```
parse_input :: String -> [(String, [Float])]
parse_input x = [ (head y, int2float (tail y)) | y <- splitinput ]
    where
        int2float x = [ read a::Float | a <- x ]
        splitinput = [ words a | a <- lines x ]
```

What bothers me most about this code is the int2float part. It combs through a list of integers and one-by-one converts each one into a float.

Is there a more efficient way to convert a list of integers into a list of floats?

Comment: Note that using `[Float]` [is generally a bad idea](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Floating_point), you might as well use `[Double]` then. If you want fast performance for simple operations use e.g. [`Data.Vector.Unboxed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html)s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not clear about what do you mean by 'efficient way' for this case?

What you are trying to do is to convert `[String]` to `[Float]`. I think using `read` will do just fine. If you really have `[Int]` then you can use `fromIntegral` to get any instance of `Num` type. Just to point you should prefer `map` instead of list comprehension as it is more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help, Sativik. I just remembered that Haskell is a lazy language, and that this code only "combs" through the numbers when it needs them. I realized this when I ran this function on an infinite list.